# MongoDB: Operator $in and results order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using the $in operator in a query in this way.

```
{ customer_id: "55681864527cb123208b4567", 
_id: { $in: [ 
"56cf29693f2c755a0a8b459f", "56cde0213f2c756b0a8b4569", "56cddfbc3f2c75580a8b4567"
] }
```

These are the results.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cddfbc3f2c75580a8b4567"), "customer_id" : "55681864527cb123208b4567", "id" : "56cddfbc3f2c75580a8b4567"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cde0213f2c756b0a8b4569"), "customer_id" : "55681864527cb123208b4567", "id" : "56cde0213f2c756b0a8b4569"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cf29693f2c755a0a8b459f"), "customer_id" : "55681864527cb123208b4567", "id" : "56cf29693f2c755a0a8b459f"}
```

The results order don't respect my search order and that make sense.

I need that the results order begin with the id **56cf29693f2c755a0a8b459f** and end with the id **56cddfbc3f2c75580a8b4567**. Respecting my search order.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cf29693f2c755a0a8b459f"), "customer_id" : "55681864527cb123208b4567", "id" : "56cf29693f2c755a0a8b459f"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cde0213f2c756b0a8b4569"), "customer_id" : "55681864527cb123208b4567", "id" : "56cde0213f2c756b0a8b4569"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cddfbc3f2c75580a8b4567"), "customer_id" : "55681864527cb123208b4567", "id" : "56cddfbc3f2c75580a8b4567"}
```

But, there is any way to achieve that?.

Thanks.

Comment: JohnnyHK, you are right. This question already has an answer.
Should I delete this one? What is the convention? Thanks in any case.

Comment: It's up to you. The system will delete it after 30 days if your duplicate question isn't deemed useful. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252955/what-do-i-do-if-my-question-happens-to-be-a-duplicate) for some guidance.